Fluent-bit is truncating java applications logs needing a script to figure out the offending log
I have read this stackoverflow post.
I have the same issue as the OP, as the some logs in my ECS container service are discarded due to its size over 256 kb.  I wondering if someone can help understand how to use the following logs by MathiasCodes so I can made adjustment to it
fluent-bit.conf: |
[SERVICE]
    Daemon                    Off
    Flush                     2
    Grace                     5
    Log_Level                 warn
    Parsers_File              parsers.conf
    HTTP_Server               ${HTTP_SERVER}
    HTTP_Listen               0.0.0.0
    HTTP_Port                 ${HTTP_PORT}
    storage.path              /var/fluent-bit/state/flb-storage/
    storage.sync              normal
    storage.checksum          off
    storage.max_chunks_up     128
    storage.backlog.mem_limit 5M
    scheduler.cap             30

@INCLUDE application-log.conf
@INCLUDE dataplane-log.conf
@INCLUDE host-log.conf

get-size.lua: |
      function cb_print(tag, timestamp, record)
          if record["log"] ~= nil then
              log_size = string.len(record["log"])
              record["log_size"] = log_size
              -- Print out all logs that are bigger than 255000 bytes
              if log_size > 255000 then
                  print(record["log"])
              end
          end
          return 1, timestamp, record
      end

application-log.conf: |
    [INPUT]
        Name                tail
        Tag                 application.*
        Exclude_Path        /var/log/containers/cloudwatch-agent*, /var/log/containers/fluent-bit*, /var/log/containers/aws-node*
        Path                /var/log/containers/*.log
        multiline.parser    java, docker, cri
        DB                  /var/fluent-bit/state/flb_container.db
        Mem_Buf_Limit       50MB
        Skip_Long_Lines     Off
        Refresh_Interval    5
        Rotate_Wait         30
        storage.type        filesystem
        Read_from_Head      ${READ_FROM_HEAD}

    [INPUT]
        Name                tail
        Tag                 application.*
        Path                /var/log/containers/cloudwatch-agent*
        multiline.parser    docker, cri
        DB                  /var/fluent-bit/state/flb_cwagent.db
        Mem_Buf_Limit       5MB
        Skip_Long_Lines     Off
        Refresh_Interval    30
        Read_from_Head      ${READ_FROM_HEAD}
    
    [FILTER]
        Name                lua
        Match               *
        script              get-size.lua
        call                cb_print

    [FILTER]
        Name                kubernetes
        Match               application.*
        Kube_URL            https://kubernetes.default.svc:443
        Kube_Tag_Prefix     application.var.log.containers.
        Merge_Log           On
        Merge_Log_Key       log_processed
        K8S-Logging.Parser  On
        K8S-Logging.Exclude Off
        Labels              On
        Annotations         Off
    
    [OUTPUT]
        Name                cloudwatch_logs
        Match               application.*
        region              ${AWS_REGION}
        log_group_name      /aws/containerinsights/${CLUSTER_NAME}/application
        log_stream_name     $(kubernetes['container_name'])-$(kubernetes['pod_name'])
        log_stream_template $kubernetes['container_name'].$kubernetes['pod_name']
        auto_create_group   On
        Retry_Limit         False

Question 1:
what does the '|' symbol do in line 1?
Question 2:
Where would I insert this function call?  In between input and output?
I tried to run the script and it did not work.


The symbol "|" marks in yaml that it is multi line content

Correct you insert it in between input and output. It is just another filter
[INPUT]
Name                tail
...

[FILTER]
Name                lua
Match               *
script              get-size.lua
call                cb_print

[OUTPUT]
Name                cloudwatch_logs
...



This is how actually my script looks like.
  get-size.lua: |
function cb_print(tag, timestamp, record)
    if record["message"] ~= nil then
        log_size = string.len(record["message"])
        record["log_size"] = log_size
        if log_size > 255000 then
            -- Print only the first 500 bytes of the message
            print(string.sub(record["message"], 1, 500))
        end
    end
    return 1, timestamp, record
end

The record itself returns a table. The output is for example table: 0x7fac475d22f3
So it can not be read directly. So this is why i access it by record["message"]. And also as I am logging my Fluent-Bit logs also to CloudWatch, then I am limiting the printing out message also to 500 first characters. This way i can have an idea, that is causing this without actually displaying the whole huge log.
